# Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject Error with embedded Youtube Video

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I have a HTML page where I embedd a youtube video with the following code:

```
<iframe width="600" 
     height="338" 
     src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/aUHdhfghhahlY?autohide=1&amp;theme=light&loop=1&playlist=edkAiJxQWHQ&amp;hd=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;showsearch=0&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;autoplay=1" >
</iframe>
```

The video runs fine, but I get the following error in my console.

```
Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://www.domain.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

"youtube-nocookie.com" redirects the HTTP request to HTTPS but uses sources inside of the page, which are not secure. So if you don't have access to the source of "youtube-nocookie.com" there is nothing you can do. If you have, use only HTTPS sources or prevent the redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: How do I prevent the redirect?